# how to animate png images using matplotlib with animation.FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, numpy-ndarray

I would like to animate an image loaded in python.
To load an image, I wrote

```
myrondarray = plt.imread(myimage.png)
myrwndarray = myrondarray.copy()
```

So myrwndarray is a RGBA array (x,y,4)

I wrote an update function to update myrwndarray, but I'm unable to use with animation.FuncAnimation because it takes a figure as input

Could you show me how to convert myrwndarray to a figure to animate it ?

If possible the init function and the update function ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you want to use matplotlib, you need to create a figure. E.g. `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`. Then `fig` is the figure to supply to the `FuncAnimation` and `ax` is the axes to plot to, e.g. `ax.imshow(myrwndarray)`. If you have a single array, it's not clear what to animate though.

Comment: The image contains a draw. I load the image in ndarray. I have a function to modify the content of the draw step by step.in the ndarray. And I want to show each step on the screen. I know that animate need of a figure, but how to show a ndarray (x,y,4) as a figure, which is (x,y). I don't want to display the axes,just the evolution of the draw.

Comment: Yes, in how far does [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html) not help?